# How to run JSON rpc with parity server?

Tags: json-rpc, parity, connections, ethcore

I use a VPS where I want to run parity to synchronize the blockchain.

I use this command :

```
parity --chain frontier.json --rpcapi="eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --rpc --rpcaddr ipAddressPub --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --author 0x...
```

I've two ip address on my vps, one public ip and one private
And when I want to run parity with the public ip I've this error :

```
RPC io error: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)
```

And when I run with private address it's working

But I want to get access to to vps to connect to the blockchain from other server, so I must to run the command with public address, isn't it?

How can I do this?

Comment: unrelated comment: why are you using frontier.json? Shouldn't it be homestead?

Comment: which operating system?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the correct answer, but it might be an idea.

Can you map the public address to the private one with some iptables rules?

I would just open one random port to the public address and redirect all the traffic to the private one.

Regards